# "Guided Access" equivalent

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have to develop a windows store app which will be usable on public devices, that means users aren't supposed to be able to quit my application.

On iOS devices, an option called "Guided Access" allows to do this easily, buttons are disabled and you can specify an area where user can interact.

After some researches, I haven't found a way to do that, it seems that Microsoft has not implemented this option in Windows 8, so I'm looking for a way to do this with some code, directly in my app but I have no idea on how to do that precisely. Please, can you tell me if it's possible and, if it is, can you give me a point where I can start ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not sure whether or not this made it into the newly released preview of the Windows 8.1 Update, but check for "Assigned Access" it was rumored to be a new feature especially for Windows store apps

Edit: See the offical 8.1 product guide [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=302189), it only mentions it two times but maybe it is worth installing the preview.

Comment: Thank you ! Microsoft plans to introduce this feature in the 8.1 update, so, maybe I just have to wait until the public release !