# Is "Assigned Access" [Windows 8.1 feature] possible in Windows 8 app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I want to create an app which will be deployed on tablets as a kiosk in a mall. I searched around for creating app with some restriction like it will be always open, only authenticated uses can close with swipe gesture or Alt+F4. I got one [solution but it's related to Win 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426387/guided-access-equivalent) and I can't wait till that.

So what I want is the app will be always on. Normal users will use the app, they can't close it. App can be close by only authenticated users with password. Anybody have any ideas to do these things ?

PS : For those who don't know what is "Assigned Access", please see [Windows 8.1 product guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=302189) and search for that term.

Comment: I wonder if something like this is possible with task scheduling and triggers, like 'When this app is closed, open the app' and 'when this app is switch away, switch to the app' type of thing. I believe you can open the app via powershell, which you can definitely schedule.

Comment: Yes, it might be possible, +1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 App on Windows 8 which cannot be closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707198/html5-app-on-windows-8-which-cannot-be-closed)

Comment: It's not dup, I am asking possible solution/workaround for Win8

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Windows 8 by design. You will have to wait until 8.1 for the dedicated "kiosk mode."

Comment: Yes I know, but I asked if anyone is having any workaround or hack way to do the same in Win 8

Answer (score 0):

It's incomplete, but if you can't wait for 8.1 consider the following 2 setting to fake a kiosk mode.

### 1. Modify the user GPO for the Kiosk account.  Change "User Config->Administrative Templates->System->Custom User interface"  Enable the policy and put in the path to your application.

This will prevent the "desktop" from loading and replace explore.exe with your applications .exe

### 2.  REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v 'Scancode Map' /t REG_BINARY /d "Make your binary change here" /f

This disables special keys like Windows key and remaps the Alt and Ctrl.  Use Sharpkeys to define the binary http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/

Good luck.

Comment: I sent you in the wrong direction.  You should set it via Group Policy.  I've updated point #1 to reflect the proper location.

Comment: If it works then how can I re-enable the desktop mode ? I doubt, I won't be able to run group policy after setting "Custom User interface"

Comment: If you need to, you could bring up task manager (via your remapped Alt-Ctrl-Del) and run "Explorer.exe"