# windows 8.1 assigned access for Desktop App

Tags: wpf, desktop-application, windows-8.1

I have a Desktop Application written in WPF (originally for Windows 7) that I would like to run in Kiosk (Assign Access mode) on a Microsoft Surface Pro 2.   The assigned access feature looked perfect, but it doesn't support non-store apps.

I just need a way to prevent the user from switching to another app or getting access to the OS etc.

Possible?

Comment: try this, I am not sure it will work or not http://stackoverflow.com/a/18660950/1230188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make your application fullscreen as shown here: [full screen wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920067/full-screen-wpf)
2. In your main window constructor subscribe on Deactivate event or override OnDeactivate method:

   ```
       Deactivated += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           Activate();
       };
   ```
3. You would also want to prevent the window from Alt+F4 closing by handling the Closing event on such a way:

   ```
       Closing += delegate(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
       {
           if(!Environment.HasShutdownStarted)
               e.Cancel = true;
       };
   ```

After all done, the application is closable only by task manager, sign out and shutdown.